# Efficient package for map on react native

Tags: react-native, android-mapview, expo, react-native-maps

I am going to build an app which will get users location on map. Than there will be a admin who want to reach these points and the map package should return a way which admin is going to take the shortes path to reach every single user.

**What is the most efficient react-native or expo package for this project?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'react-native-maps', I have used it in my projects and it's really good.
Expo also provides `react-native-maps` out of the box. and it has good community support too. 
Or you can even use `mapbox`. It is cheaper but I haven't tested it yet.

`react-native-maps`
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps

`mapbox`
https://www.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-react-native-sdk/

Comment: what do you mean by cheaper?

Comment: If you plan to build a large scale app, google maps are not free

Comment: Actually react-native-maps uses google maps as default in android. After configuring if your app uses google maps api, you have to pay.